# The specified type member 'Product' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm getting the error 'Product' is not supported in LINQ to Entities whilst using cartItems.Product.UnitCost when trying to get the total of the basket.

```
public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        //Multiply price by count of item to get price for each item in cart and them sum all prices up
        decimal? total = (from cartItems in db.ShoppingBaskets where cartItems.BasketID == ShoppingCartID select (int?)cartItems.BasketQuantity * cartItems.Product.UnitCost).Sum();

        return total ?? decimal.Zero;
    }
```

I then tried splitting the query up to see if this would fix the problem

```
int? quantity = (from cartItems in db.ShoppingBaskets where cartItems.BasketID == ShoppingCartID select (int?)cartItems.BasketQuantity).Sum();

decimal? price = (from cartItems in db.ShoppingBaskets where cartItems.BasketID == ShoppingCartID select cartItems.Product.UnitCost).Sum();
```

I get the same problem with the second separate query with 'Product'.

Product Class

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.OrderCheckouts = new HashSet<OrderCheckout>();
        this.ProductReviews = new HashSet<ProductReview>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public int UnitQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductImage { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderCheckout> OrderCheckouts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductReview> ProductReviews { get; set; }
}
```

ShoppingBasket Class

```
public partial class ShoppingBasket
{
    public int CartID { get; set; }
    public string BasketID { get; set; }
    public int BasketQuantity { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Could someone explain the problem more clearly and how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you converting to a nullable? Are you expecting quantity or price to be null? If so, why?

Comment: This message makes me think `Product` isn't translating to Entity Framework from `db.ShoppingBaskets`. Not a specific issue with `Product`. Can you edit your question with `ShoppingBasket`?

Comment: I was just seeing if converting to nullable would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Entity Framework hasn't fully created the relationship between `ShoppingBasket` and `Product`. Try adding:

```
public virtual ICollection<ShoppingBasket> ShoppingBaskets { get; set; }
```

to the `Product` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3015121 Does `Product` work in other places in your application? For example, does `db.Products` work?